# Will_Paginate --- Set the Starting record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I have a photo_album
which has several photos, IDs: 4,9,10,11,31 -- all for photo_album:3

I have the following for my DEF SHOW in my Photos controller:

```
@photo = @photoalbum.photos.order("created_at ASC").paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 1
```

Problem is, if the URL is: /photo_albums/3/photos/10 The code above starts at record 4, when I want it to start the will paginate at 10, like in the URL.

Anyone know how to set the starting ID in will_paginate?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Also, noticing the PAGINATION links are rendering link this:

```
/photos/10?page=2&photo_album_id=3
```

When they should be rendering like:

```
/photo_albums/3/photos/?page=2
```

Does that sound right?

Here's the model info:

```
class PhotoAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :photo_album
```

**Update 2 - Desired User Flow...**

- #1 - User sees a list of photo albums
- #2, Users clicks a Photo Albums
- #3 User see a list of photos in the album
- #4 use views the clicked photo BUT has will_paginate showing and
  defaulted to the page number of the
  photo the user clicked

**Update 3 - Controllers based on the flow**

- Photo Albums per Project - PhotoAlbum Index
- Photos Per Photo Album - PhotoAlbum Show
- Photo Show  - Photo Show

Does this sound right? Still at it, no luck yet. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363881/jesse-wolgamott) pointed out, you should be using `index` to display a list of photos, not `show`, even though you are only showing one photo per page.

Using the finder in your controller gives you a WillPaginate object in your view:

```
def index
  @photos = @photoalbum.photos.order("created_at ASC").paginate :page => params[:page],
    per_page => 1
end
```

In the view, will_paginate knows about the has_many relationship, so it will include the params for the parent photo_album

```
<%= will_paginate(@photos) %>
```

renders the next link as:

```
/photos?page=2&photo_album_id=3
```

You might have expected `/photo_albums/3/photos?page=2`, but will_paginate does not use the nested resource path. That's OK, because the URL ends up in the same place, i.e. `{ :controller => :photos, :action => :index, :photo_album_id => 3 }`

You can pass in the parent explicitly to override if necessary:

```
<%= will_paginate(@photos,:params => {:photo_album_id => 3}) %>
```

More info in the [`will_paginate docs`](http://gitrdoc.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master)

**EDIT**

> OK Thanks but what about showing a
>   "STARTING RECORD" meaning if an album
>   has 8 photos, and the user clicks to
>   see photo 4, how to I show that photo
>   in the right pagination order, using
>   the INDEX ?

You could add the page number to the link in the album view. Maybe something like this:

```
<% @photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| do %>
  <%= link_to "View photo",
    photo_album_photos_path(@photo_album, :page => index) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: OK Thanks but what about showing a "STARTING RECORD" meaning if an album has 8 photos, and the user clicks to see photo 4, how to I show that photo in the right pagination order, using the INDEX ?

Comment: Also, how should I be linking to the photo view page? I have "photo_path(photo)" currently but that goes to the show page, and it sounds like your saying I need to use INDEX?

Comment: So the underlining issues is that I have a PhotoAlbum Index, and it can't be used to display a list of photoalbums, and render the photos. Two separate views? Right

Comment: undefined method `photo_album_photo_path' for #<#<Class:0x107cd04d0>:0x107cce108>

Comment: Damn, you're quick :) Try `photo_album_photos_path(@photo_album)`, or pass in the photoalbum ID.

Comment: thanks, I did that, but remember that's on the page that is showing all the thumbnails of photos contained in a photoalbum. SO that link is the same for every photo which is bad. It should link to the page where the user can view the photo but it should contain a photoID so willpaginate knows which photo to display? right?

Comment: oh it worked! Also the index was a great idea, but index starts at 0, so I had to do index+1

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent the last 5 hours on this one!

Comment: The links won't be the same -- each link goes to a different page. The URL should not include the photo id -- it will pull the correct photo object out of the paginated collection based on the requested page number. You could easily extend this later to show more than one photo in the paginated view, if necessary, by increasing `:per_page`. At the risk of complicating matters, you *could* show one photo by using a `show` action, finding the photo by the ID, and (somehow) generating the prev/next links, but using `index` action will be easier because it fits within the will_paginate paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a Show method. To use Pagination, you should be on the Index method of the PhotoAlbum controller.

so your links should be

```
link_to('Show Photos', photo_album_path(@photo_album, page=>params[:page])
```

If you want to Show only one photo, cool, but don't use pagination.

```
link_to('Photo), photo_album_photo_path(@photo_album, @photo))
```

Comment: thanks this is interesting. Just to make sure I'm being clear about the Flow. #1 - User sees a list of photo albums, #2, Users clicks a Photo Albums, #3 User see a list of photos in the album, #4 use views the clicked photo BUT has will_pagine showing and defaulted to the page number of the photo the user clicked.

Comment: Given the above, where would your Link_to be? I need help creating the photos links for #3?

Comment: The PhotoAlbum INDEX shows a list of all the user's photo albums, not the list of photos in the album.

Comment: What and where does "page=>params[:page]" come from? Trying to understand how I use that to set the starting photo in the album?